# Fastest way to delete a non empty directory in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, rsync, rm

I use the command **rm -rf directory** but i came across the following article : [Article](http://linuxnote.net/jianingy/en/linux/a-fast-way-to-remove-huge-number-of-files.html)
That suggests that rsynch to an empty folder is the fastest way? **rsync -a –delete empty/ a** Why is this the case ?
Is there another faster method to delete a nonEmpty folder ?

Another interesting article about this [Article2](http://www.slashroot.in/which-is-the-fastest-method-to-delete-files-in-linux)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found that the fastest and most memory-efficient solution is to use this command in the directory full with millions of files:

```
ls -f1 | xargs rm
```

**Explanation**

Because `ls -f1` will not sort the directory content, it will start the output right away. The `rm` command will take just one argument: the actual file name coming from the first command.
It was the only solution to delete 3.000.000 files from a Magento webshop's session directory. The server ran on a virtual machine with just 2Gb of RAM - it was no other possibility to delete the files.

Comment: Doesn't `rm -rf` delete files one-by-one too?

Answer (score 4):

Based on a very quick glimpse at GNU Coreutils 8.21 and rsync 3.0.1 sources plus taking a look what they do with the strace, the rm from GNU Coreutils seems to call malloc() quite a bit more than rsync does when performing the same thing. I'm doubt this explains the speed difference completely, though, but it's part of the explanation most likely.